# Estimate tx size

Tags: rpc, bitcoin, bitcoind

I need to know transaction size to calculate fee user is going to spend by sending BTC. I use `bitcoind` wallet with many accounts and use `sendtoaddress` call to send BTC. Is there any way to know how many outputs `bitcoind` will use to create transaction? Or maybe other way to know transaction size before `bitcoind` executes it...

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to create the transaction by yourself

> Is there any way to know how many outputs bitcoind will use to create transaction?

The outputs are defined by you, I guess, what you are looking for here are the inputs (UTXOs), for sample [`sendtoaddress`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/sendtoaddress/) is defined to create a transaction with one output, while [`sendmany`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/sendmany/) will create a transaction with multiple outputs as you provide in the parameters.

Using RPC, you can skip the input selection by doing as the following example:

```
// creates a rawtransaction with no inputs
bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction "[]" "{\"btc01...receiveraddress\":0.01}"
// fund the transaction with the missing inputs and calculate the fee
bitcoin-cli fundrawtransaction ...hash_response_from_createrawtransaction
```

[`fundrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/fundrawtransaction/) will add any missing inputs and calculate the fee as you will see in the response.

If you still want the transaction size, you can get it by calling [`decoderawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/decoderawtransaction/) with the hash you have generated, or just calculating it by the hash itself, just divide the hash size by two.

For more control while creating your transactions, I'd suggest you to use [`listunspent`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/listunspent/) and select the inputs by yourself

Docs:
[`createrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/)

Worth to give a look to this [transaction size calculator](https://bitcoinops.org/en/tools/calc-size/) to understand how to calculate the transaction size based in the (in/out)puts.